# Bulk chirp creation in Matlab

Tags: matlab

This is more some assistance in helping to automate chirp creation using the signal processing tools.

So basically using the chirp tool I'm trying to see if I can bulk generate 990 chirps (in a frequency range of 5-500Hz both upsweep and downsweep) so I can then do some statistics on them to define a best fit model through correlation without physically having to type out and generate all these chirps.

Example:

```
ch_6_60_10_lin=chirp(0:0.004:10,6,10,60,'linear',90);
```

To generate a chirp between 6Hz and 60Hz over a 10s interval.

I want to be able to generate 495 variables in these formats

```
ch_5_[5:500]_10_lin=chirp(0:0.004:10,5,10,[5:500],'linear',90) % where [5:500] are 495 steps
ch_[5:500]_500_10_lin=chirp(0:0.004:10,[5:500],10,500,'linear',90)
```

Any pointers in the right direction would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you want all of those as independent variables?  It would probably be easier to manage all of this as a matrix.

```
tVec = 0:0.004:10; % Vector of time samples
f1Vec = 5:500; % Vector of ending frequencies for the first set of chirps
f2Vec = 5:000; % Vector of starting frequencies for the second set of chirps

nChirps1 = length(f1Vec);
nChirps2 = length(f2Vec);

nTimeSamples = length(tVec);

chirpMat1 = zeros(nChirps1, nTimeSamples);
chirpMat2 = zeros(nChirps2, nTimeSamples);

for iChirp = 1:nChirps1
    chirpMat1(iChirp, :) = chirp(tVec, 5, 10, f1Vec(iChirp), 'linear', 90);
end

for iChirp = 1:nChirps2
    chirpMat2(iChirp, :) = chirp(tVec, f0Vec(iChirp), 10, 500, 'linear', 90);
end
```